# How to debug/read/exmine Zend objects (Gdata)

Tags: php, zend-framework, gdata

I'm fairly new to Zend Framework and my only OOP experience is with CakePHP. When using Zend Gdata it troubles me that when I `print_r` / `var_dump` objects returned from the API are not readable. Since I'm not used to working this way, it's pretty much trial and error getting to the correct attributes.

Is there some way to make these objects more readable, so I can easily discover the attributes that are available?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install xdebug php extension, this will make var_dumps readable.
Another thing that may simplify your zf developer's life is ZFDebug which will add onpage toolbar that will show you some valuable information like execution times, sql queries log etc.